# How to safely store users facebook profile link? PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, hyperlink, sanitization

I orignally posted asking how I can store a users facebook profile link, to use it on a profile page that I was creating on my website and didn't really get much of a response. After spending a lot of time I have a system in place that I feel should work but doesn't.

I'm not entirely comfortable with AJAX yet and have tried adapting code from Adam Khoury's Web Intersect 2.0 series to suit my project.

I've pasted my code over at Pastebin http://pastebin.com/u/lil_bugga test2.php being my main form with the Ajax and link_checker.php being my include file. Can someone help me to get this code working properly.

Its meant to take the user input, sanitize it and return 1 of 4 different result that I can then use to display appropriate messages to the user. The code seems to work fine until after the following line in test2.php

```
alert(params.join("&"));
```

Below is my orignal question for any interested parties.

*"How can I safely collect and store links supplied by a site visitor as part of their profile, if they wish to provide it.*

*I know I don't want to store it without sanitization of some form but I would assume using something like the snippet below would leave me vulnerable to attack.*

```
$username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_/:]#i'
```

*I also want to compare the supplied links against a url list i.e:*

```
http:// www.facebook.com/userprofile
www.facebook.com/1234567890
```

*Whats the best option here, as some people may submit with HTTP:// others with just WWW. and some even just facebook.com/ and then theres the (userprofile) name or the user id (1234567890)"*

Comment: Why don't you create an app, tells them to login on fb through your it and grab the info by the API ?

Comment: I'm hoping to be able to catch peoples other social media accounts too like twitter, google+, youtube etc so once I have a system inplace for one I can modify to work for the rest

Comment: You are mixing up two different issues here: _Security_ and _validation for plausibility_.

Comment: Am I? I thought that as my AJAX was passing data to php which then sanitizes the code it would be enough to safely store that link inside my database. The link validation is just to ensure that the links provided to me meet the format I want and will take you to the right site if clicked upon.